# Looping through table returns undefined results

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to make a dropdown of activities that a user can delete. The activities are held in a table which I'm trying to iterate over but I feel like I am almost there. I use Bootstrap 3 and jQuery. I'm still new to jQuery.

Here is the HTML I use to create a modal window, so I can put the control in there:

```
<div id="delete-activity-modal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h1>Delete Activity</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon" id="add-addon-styling">Choose Activity</span>
                    <select class="form-control" id="delete-activity-modal-dropdown">
                        <!-- Options Added via content-controller.js -->
                    </select>
                    <span class="input-group-addon" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top"
                          title="Choose the activity from the drop-down menu you want to delete.">
                        <b>?</b>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-bg" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: Result]

As you see above, that's what I get out. I should have had 6 results and they should have an activity ID and a Name but they come back as undefined so I'm probably doing it wrong :P

Here is the function I use to make the dropdown content:

```
function CreateActivityDeleteDropdown() {
    var dropdown = $('#delete-activity-modal-dropdown');
    $('#activityTable').each(function() {
        var activityId = $(this).attr("#activityId");
        var activityName = $(this).attr("#activityName");
        var dropdownDescription = activityId + " | " + activityName;
        var dropdownElement = '<option value="' + activityId + '">' + dropdownDescription + '</option>';
        $(dropdown).append(dropdownElement);
    });
}
```

This function is only called when you press a button, so the table does exist when I do this. The table that I need to look through is dynamically added when the website loads like this:

```
function GetActivityAbstracts() {
    $.getJSON(, function (testData) {
        var object = $.parseJSON(testData);
        var activityTable = '<tbody id="activityTable"></tbody>';
        $.each(object, function () {
            var activityId = this['ActivityId'];
            var activityName = this['ActivityName'];
            var activityResponsible = this['Responsible'];
            var activityEstimatedSavings = parseFloat(this['EstimatedSavings']).toFixed(2);
            var activityEstimatedStart = this['EstimatedStart'];
            var activityEstimatedEnd = this['EstimatedEnd'];
            var activityStatus = this['Status'];
            // TODO: Make more user-friendly Status Descriptions instead of C# enum values.
            var tableElement =
                    '<tr>' +
                    '<td id = "activityId" style = "vertical-align: middle; align: center;">'
                    + activityId + '</td>' +
                    '<td style = "vertical-align: middle;">' +
                    '<div class="status-circle" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right"' +
                    'title=" ' + activityStatus + '" style="background-color:' +
                    GetColumnColor(activityStatus) + ';"></div></td>' +
                    '<td id = "activityName" style = "vertical-align: middle;">'
                    + activityName + '</td>' +
                    '<td style = "vertical-align: middle;">'
                    + activityResponsible + '</td>' +
                    '<td style = "vertical-align: middle;">'
                    + activityEstimatedSavings + '</td>' +
                    '<td style = "vertical-align: middle;">'
                    + activityEstimatedStart + '</td>' +
                    '<td style = "vertical-align: middle;">'
                    + activityEstimatedEnd + '</td>' +
                    '</tr>';
            activityTable += tableElement;
        });
        $('#current-data-table').append(activityTable);

        /* This call is necessary because the table is added dynamically */
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"').tooltip();
    });
}
```

The result:

[image]

Some JSON Sample data:

```
"{\"1\":{\"ActivityId\":1,\"ActivityName\":\"Noget Med Penge\",\"Responsible\":\"Name\",\"EstimatedSavings\":9001.0,\"EstimatedStart\":\"19-11-2015\",\"EstimatedEnd\":\"01-01-2016\",\"Status\":\"NA\"},\"2\":{\"ActivityId\":2,\"ActivityName\":\"We need to shut down the bluetooth RAM hard drive!\",\"Responsible\":\"Name\",\"EstimatedSavings\":24589.0,\"EstimatedStart\":\"23-05-2014\",\"EstimatedEnd\":\"10-12-2015\",\"Status\":\"ON_TRACK\"},\"3\":{\"ActivityId\":3,\"ActivityName\":\"We need to encode the wireless RAM interface!\",\"Responsible\":\"Name\",\"EstimatedSavings\":874561.0,\"EstimatedStart\":\"11-04-1970\",\"EstimatedEnd\":\"22-01-2016\",\"Status\":\"DONE\"},\"4\":{\"ActivityId\":4,\"ActivityName\":\"We need to reboot the open-source PNG program!\",\"Responsible\":\"Name\",\"EstimatedSavings\":812654.0,\"EstimatedStart\":\"18-08-2000\",\"EstimatedEnd\":\"19-04-2016\",\"Status\":\"ISSUE\"},\"5\":{\"ActivityId\":5,\"ActivityName\":\"We need to program 
the mobile CPU bus!\",\"Responsible\":\"Name\",\"EstimatedSavings\":-47998.0,\"EstimatedStart\":\"29-07-1982\",\"EstimatedEnd\":\"22-05-2016\",\"Status\":\"BEHIND\"},\"6\":{\"ActivityId\":6,\"ActivityName\":\"We need to network the optical GB port!\",\"Responsible\":\"Name\",\"EstimatedSavings\":74511.0,\"EstimatedStart\":\"23-10-1992\",\"EstimatedEnd\":\"27-09-2016\",\"Status\":\"ABANDONED\"}}"
```

Comment: Can you add html pls?

Comment: Every `each()` is searching for each `<tbody id="activity-table">` now. You need to either do `$('#activityTable tr').each()` or `$('#activityTable tr td').each()`. The 1st one gets all the tr's, and the 2nd one gets all the td's in the tr's. (Looking at your code, you need the 2nd one)

Comment: Your `GetActivityAbstracts` will create elements with duplicate `id`s which is invalid..

Comment: @GuruprasadRao Can you elaborate on why that is? The information that it pulls is served from a Database.

Comment: @LJa Alright thanks, I'll have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all `GetActivityAbstracts` will create duplicate `id`s as I said. In the above code `<td id = "activityId"` and `<td id = "activityName"` inside `$.each` will be duplicate. Also use **[`.find`](https://api.jquery.com/find/)** instead of **[`.attr`](https://api.jquery.com/attr/)** to find the elements inside each `tr` So you either change `id` to class or add `index` from `.each` to generate unique `id`s.

```
function GetActivityAbstracts() {
    $.getJSON(, function (testData) {
        var object = $.parseJSON(testData);
        var activityTable = '<tbody id="activityTable"></tbody>';
        $.each(object, function (index,value) {
            //index here is used to generate unique ids
            var activityId = this['ActivityId'];
            var activityName = this['ActivityName'];
            var activityResponsible = this['Responsible'];
            var activityEstimatedSavings = parseFloat(this['EstimatedSavings']).toFixed(2);
            var activityEstimatedStart = this['EstimatedStart'];
            var activityEstimatedEnd = this['EstimatedEnd'];
            var activityStatus = this['Status'];
            // TODO: Make more user-friendly Status Descriptions instead of C# enum values.
            var tableElement =
                    '<tr>' +
                    '<td id = "activityId_'+index+'" style = "vertical-align: middle; align: center;">'
                    + activityId + '</td>' +
                    '<td style = "vertical-align: middle;">' +
                    '<div class="status-circle" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right"' +
                    'title=" ' + activityStatus + '" style="background-color:' +
                    GetColumnColor(activityStatus) + ';"></div></td>' +
                    '<td id = "activityName_'+index+'" style = "vertical-align: middle;">'
                    + activityName + '</td>' +
                    //Add index for ids here
                    '<td style = "vertical-align: middle;">'
                    + activityResponsible + '</td>' +
                    '<td style = "vertical-align: middle;">'
                    + activityEstimatedSavings + '</td>' +
                    '<td style = "vertical-align: middle;">'
                    + activityEstimatedStart + '</td>' +
                    '<td style = "vertical-align: middle;">'
                    + activityEstimatedEnd + '</td>' +
                    '</tr>';
            activityTable += tableElement;
        });
        $('#current-data-table').append(activityTable);

        /* This call is necessary because the table is added dynamically */
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"').tooltip();
    });
}
```

Now once you have this **unique elements** generated you can loop through each `tr`s as below:

```
function CreateActivityDeleteDropdown() {
    var dropdown = $('#delete-activity-modal-dropdown');
    $('tbody#activityTable tr').each(function() {
        var activityId = $(this).find("td [id^='activityId']").text();
        //get value from the td whose id starts with activityId
        var activityName = $(this).find("td [id^='activityName']").text();
        //get value from the td whose id start with activityName
        var dropdownDescription = activityId + " | " + activityName;
        var dropdownElement = '<option value="' + activityId + '">' + dropdownDescription + '</option>';
        $(dropdown).append(dropdownElement);
    });
}
```

Now if you change `td`'s `id` to `class` as below:

```
function GetActivityAbstracts() {
    $.getJSON(, function (testData) {
        var object = $.parseJSON(testData);
        var activityTable = '<tbody id="activityTable"></tbody>';
        $.each(object, function () {
            var activityId = this['ActivityId'];
            var activityName = this['ActivityName'];
            var activityResponsible = this['Responsible'];
            var activityEstimatedSavings = parseFloat(this['EstimatedSavings']).toFixed(2);
            var activityEstimatedStart = this['EstimatedStart'];
            var activityEstimatedEnd = this['EstimatedEnd'];
            var activityStatus = this['Status'];
            // TODO: Make more user-friendly Status Descriptions instead of C# enum values.
            var tableElement =
                    '<tr>' +
                    '<td class = "activityId" style = "vertical-align: middle; align: center;">'
                    + activityId + '</td>' +
                    '<td style = "vertical-align: middle;">' +
                    '<div class="status-circle" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right"' +
                    'title=" ' + activityStatus + '" style="background-color:' +
                    GetColumnColor(activityStatus) + ';"></div></td>' +
                    '<td class= "activityName" style = "vertical-align: middle;">'
                    + activityName + '</td>' +
                    '<td style = "vertical-align: middle;">'
                    + activityResponsible + '</td>' +
                    '<td style = "vertical-align: middle;">'
                    + activityEstimatedSavings + '</td>' +
                    '<td style = "vertical-align: middle;">'
                    + activityEstimatedStart + '</td>' +
                    '<td style = "vertical-align: middle;">'
                    + activityEstimatedEnd + '</td>' +
                    '</tr>';
            activityTable += tableElement;
        });
        $('#current-data-table').append(activityTable);

        /* This call is necessary because the table is added dynamically */
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"').tooltip();
    });
}
```

You can just use **[`.find`](https://api.jquery.com/find/)** again to get respective `td` with its `class` as below:

```
function CreateActivityDeleteDropdown() {
    var dropdown = $('#delete-activity-modal-dropdown');
    $('#activityTable tr td').each(function() {
        var activityId = $(this).find(".activityId").text();
        var activityName = $(this).find(".activityName").text();
        //getting using class
        var dropdownDescription = activityId + " | " + activityName;
        var dropdownElement = '<option value="' + activityId + '">' + dropdownDescription + '</option>';
        $(dropdown).append(dropdownElement);
    });
}
```

---

**Update**

Some more problems identified while creating **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/4o9aozx9/2/)**

You were having `var activityTable = '<tbody id="activityTable"></tbody>';` and then at the end, once you create a row you use to do `activityTable += tableElement;`. Since 'activityTable`variable already had`activityTable +=`used to append as`...'`which is why a new`tbody`was getting created when appended to`DOM`. So either make it`tbody` object by doing as below:

```
var activityTable = $('<tbody id="activityTable"></tbody>');
```

and then you can use `.append` to `append` the `tr` inside the created `tbody` as below:

```
$(activityTable).append(tableElement);
```

instead of `activityTable += tableElement;`

**OR**

If you prefer to keep your way then just append `</tbody>` once all the `rows` have been added as below:

`var activityTable = '<tbody id="activityTable">';` //remove  from here

and after `$.each` finishes you can just do

```
activityTable+="</table>";
```

Comment: Why would it create duplicate IDs?? The data that I use is served from a webservice connected to a database. The data that you get out from that can't be duplicate so why would the script produce duplicates?

Comment: Isn't each element in the table encapsulated by the <td> element?

Comment: and yea you have to use **[`.find`](https://api.jquery.com/find/)** instead of **[`.attr`](https://api.jquery.com/attr/)**

Comment: But that's going to be inaccurate...what if I have 6 activities that goes with id numbers 1, 4, 5, 40, 3234 and 55435? Then those index numbers I just assigned are completely wrong.

Comment: You just want unique `id`s, thats why `index` is used, however, the value inside those elements will be one you fetched from Database.

Comment: Those are `id`s for `elements` you create dynamically and not their `values`. Hope I am making it clear to you..

Comment: Yeah just tried your solution. Directly copy and paste. It doesn't work. The dropdown is empty.

Comment: Added some sample data to the post

Comment: @Vipar Added demo and some points.. check and let me know.. :)

Comment: Thank you. Finally through with this! :) I figured out I was making an extra tbody as well while waiting but your function to create a dropdown works great. Thanks!

Comment: Anytime.. Happy Coding.. :)

Answer (score 0):

## Edit (example):

HTML:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>
            Activity ID
        </th>
        <th>
            Status
        </th>
        <th>
            Activity name
        </th>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="activityTable">
    </tbody>
</table>

<select>
</select>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var JSONData = [[1,1,"name1"], [2,1,"name2"]];
    var html = "";
    var count = 0;
    $.each(JSONData, function(){
        html += "<tr>";
        html += "<td data-type='id'>" + JSONData[count][0] + "</td>";
        html += "<td data-type='status'>" + JSONData[count][1] + "</td>";
        html += "<td data-type='name'>" + JSONData[count][2] + "</td>";
        html += "</tr>";
        count++;
    });
    var createOption;
    $("#activityTable").html(html);
    $("select").html("");
    $("#activityTable tr").each(function(){
        var data_id = $(this).find("td[data-type=id]").html();
        var data_name = $(this).find("td[data-type=name]").html();
        createOption = "<option>" + data_id + " | " + data_name;
        $("select").append(createOption);
    });
});
```

Output:

[image]

## Demo: [Click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9FwA.png)

Comment: Hmm, the dropdown is just empty now.

Comment: Could you post the HTML of the table? (when you press inspect element on the table)?